# how to access parent window attributes that was clicked (using jquery)?

Tags: jquery, parent-child

(edited) so i've included the full test code, but initially i thought there was some way to know the parent's clicked element from the child without passing that info manually from parent. In this example, i saved that value into a 'newpage' variable to be accessed on the child page. besides this method and passing the variable through a url querystring, is there any other method to pass the info over to child??

(original question)
let's say i have something simple from a parent snippet, and once i'm in my child window and it is clicked the newWindow2 event will be fired, I would like to access the parent's clicked element data-quoteid.

parent.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var windowSizeArray = [ "width=200,height=200",
                                "width=300,height=400,scrollbars=yes" ];

        var newpage;

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.newWindow').click(function (event){

                var url = $(this).attr("href");
                var windowName = "popUp";//$(this).attr("name");
                var windowSize = windowSizeArray[$(this).attr("rel")];

                x = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-quoteid');
                                  alert(x);

                newpage = x;
                window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);

                event.preventDefault();

            });
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li id="test1" name="googlename" data-quoteid="googlequote123">
            <a href="open.html" rel="0" class="newWindow" >click me</a>
        </li>
        <li id="test2" name="yahooname" data-quoteid="yahooquote123">
            <a href="open.html" rel="1" class="newWindow" >click me</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

and then in child open.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var windowSizeArray = [ "width=200,height=200",
                                "width=300,height=400,scrollbars=yes" ];

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.newWindow2').click(function (event){

                 if(window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
                        alert(window.opener.newpage);
                    }                    

                event.preventDefault();

            });
        });


    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div name="divnamehere">test details here</div>


    <a href="#" class="newWindow2">click me</a>
</body>
```

so in this example, I first clicked on the 2nd 'click me' from parent.html using data-quoteid="yahooquote123"

I would like the alert to return me that instead of using something like window.opener.$('#test2').attr('data-quoteid') since i don't want to select by any id but by the element that was clicked to open the child originally.

Comment: Your popup knows nothing about which of those two links were clicked to open it. The only place where you have this information available, is in your parent.html - so you need to handle the click event there and store that information.

Comment: Btw., with the code as shown your links in the parent.html do not even open any new windows, you left out the part that actually achieves this functionality.

Comment: Also could pass the `quoteid` in query string of url when you open new window and parse the url in child page